# Empty Lines in HTML source bad for seo?

Tags: html, seo, removing-whitespace

I prefer to write my HTML clear, so I may use empty lines here and there - example:

```
<div>

    <!-- Seasons -->
    <table class="giantTable">
        ...
    </table>

    <!-- Prices -->
    <table class="giantTable">
        ...
    </table>

</div>
```

Today my new workmate told me that this is bad for SEO,
because Google would need more time for parsing the site and may abort with a timeout.

I never heard about this,
shall I really write Spaghetti-Code again?

Comment: It sounds like complete nonsense. The extra parsing overhead would never be so high that it would cause a timeout.

Comment: Never heard of this...

Comment: Your new workmate is an idiot. That overhead is minor.  +1 for checking on something that sounds ridiculous, unlike your workmate.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Google do use [page-load and rendering time](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2010/04/using-site-speed-in-web-search-ranking.html) as one metric (of over 200!) for determining your page-rank, so to an extent your colleague is right (although timeout's are not the issue - he is wrong on that).

However, you can have the best of both worlds :) Write your HTML as you normally do, and then [minify it](http://code.google.com/p/htmlcompressor/) before deployment.

Note that there are a number of tools for analysing your site performance (both online, and as browser plugins - e.g. YSlow), and it's a very sensible thing to do. You can have numerous bottlenecks in your web-site, and can often get some quick wins that significantly improve the responsiveness of your site.

As always with optimisation though - measure first! Don't just randomly implement supposed improvements until you have measured the bottlenecks, and then confirmed the improvement *is* an improvement.

Answer (score 2):

The sentiment isn't entirely off. Google does now consider the speed of your pages as a factor, and excessive white-space in code can increase payload size. Google themselves recommend minifying your code ( https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/best-practices/payload#MinifyHTML ), and this can be done without too much overhead on the web server.

I find the biggest culprit in dynamic websites comes from using loads of space in the middle of for/while loops, so cutting down on that can make a big difference. Also, try using tabs instead of spaces and you'll cut your white-space big-time.

Answer (score 2):

Even if this were true (which I've never heard before however RBs point above makes a good point), there are many other things that contribute to your page ranking way more than what that would.

Google made an awesome SEO guide which I always check out, its really pretty and easy to read as well, what with all the pictures of Robots. Its definitely worth checking out - [Google SEO Guide](http://static.googleusercontent.com/external_content/untrusted_dlcp/www.google.com/en//webmasters/docs/search-engine-optimization-starter-guide.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

It isn't bad at all, they ignore white space.  Otherwise everyone would be trying to write code all on one line

http://jamesmartell.com/matt-cutts/is-excessive-whitespace-in-the-html-source-bad/

Answer (score 1):

[This document](http://static.googleusercontent.com/external_content/untrusted_dlcp/www.google.com/en//webmasters/docs/search-engine-optimization-starter-guide.pdf) describes how to do SEO for Google (it is quite extensive). A first glance over all the pages doesn't say **anything** about compressing your HTML.